# Autolayout, several UILabels, lines in each, same font size?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-autolayout

I have a number of UILabels on a view and a varying amount of text in each. I need the font size to be the same in each.

I’m using autolayout to position / size the labels.

However some of the “g” characters are being cut off.

I’m not sure how I can resolve this ?

Comment: Try to change font size by your own. Setup the same size to that labels via outlets.

Comment: But I won’t know which font size I should use for the biggest text, then reflect that in all the labels ?

Comment: Uilabel has methods for size calculations. You should setup rect size and calculate font. After setup it to all other.

Comment: I assume you mean the adjust width method? Unfortunately this doesn’t cater for height e.g. “g”

Comment: What is the view and autolayout structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SizeToFit fixes my issue, rather than autolayout

Answer (score 0):

change the lines property of the lables to 0 and hook then properly to each other or to the superView so when there content is large they wrap smoothly

Comment: That will make in wrap, which I’m doing, but won’t change the font size, to make it fit ?

Comment: why you need font to fit if u wrap them

Comment: I’m not sure why “g”s are getting cut off, maybe it’s because it’s a custom font ?

Comment: can u share a screenshot of the case

Answer (score 0):

You ***cannot*** control font size directly via auto-layout constraints. You can disable adjusting font on all labels and this way they will have same label.

But to better help answering your question (and underlaying issue you're trying to solve) - it would be much better if you share screenshot with your interface.